# Algorithm to fit people in a monthly calendar

Tags: javascript, algorithm, svelte

I have an interesting algorithm to build and I have tried a couple of things but couldn't get it just right.

I have the following set of rules:

- 16 people to fill every day of the month (let's call it 28 days to make it even weeks)
- 4 people per day
- Each person should have a maximum of 7 days a month
- There has to be two days between each picked day (so if Person1 has a Monday, they shouldn't have another shift on Saturday-Sunday before nor Tuesday-Wednesday after)
- Each person should have a free weekend during the month (we include Fridays during weekends, so no shifts on Fri-Sat-Sun once)

What I've tried so far (there's not a lot of svelte-specific code, mostly js):

https://svelte.dev/repl/0fc5a8e1b2a241a9985950c6a0a1ec43?version=3.44.3

https://svelte.dev/repl/c66a7de71cda46ec94fc1e11811a6883?version=3.44.3

They are similar approaches, where the first one goes over each day in the range and tries to pick people one day at a time and the second one goes over people and tries to pick all of that person's days at once.

My issue with both of those approaches is that usually there will be days where not all people are selected.

Is there a way to improve the algorithm? Do I have another way to go about this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: hmmm it "sort of" works, but it doesn't comply with the stated rules, that's why I post it here. I'll check CodeReview as well

Comment: You should handle this by creating rotations. Since there are 16 people and 4 people are required a day, let the same 4 people work on each day. This way at least the problem is simplified to just 4 rotations and handling time off for everyone that shares the rotation.

Comment: unfortunately that's not an option, at least not in groups of 4. I'll try with smaller teams, perhaps there's an improvement

Comment: Why aren't groups of four an option?  If there are additional requirements, you need to tell us about them up front.

Comment: If you reason by total workdays capacity (16 people times 7 days max. = 112) vs. total workdays required (28 days times 4 people min. = 112), it becomes quite obvious there's not much wiggle room (and a month **cannot** be more than 28 days or at least one requirement wil not be met).

Comment: Might be worth taking a look at https://scheduling.philipithomas.com/